# Solr More Like This result not as expected, Start field other than 0 shows no result

Tags: json, solr, lucene, morelikethis, solr6

My More Like This query doesn't return the results for any **start** value other than 0.

My Query URLs with Responses are below:

http://IP_ADDRESS:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=one:ABC&mlt=true&mlt.fl=one,two,three&&rows=100&start=0&wt=json

The above works Fine.

http://IP_ADDRESS:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select?indent=on&q=one:ABC&mlt=true&mlt.fl=one,two,three&&rows=100&start=1&wt=json

The above query throws the below result:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"one:ABC",
      "mlt":"true",
      "indent":"on",
      "mlt.fl":"one, two, three",
      "start":"1",
      "rows":"100",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":1,"docs":[]
  },
  "moreLikeThis":{}}
```

I'm using solr 6.3 and the Schema for MLT that i used is below:

```
    <requestHandler name="mlt_tracks" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">

    <lst name="defaults">

    <str name="mlt.fl">one, two, three </str>

    <str name="mlt.mintf">2</str>

    <str name="rows">10</str>

    <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>

    <str name="mlt.boost">true</str>

    </lst>

    </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define mlt defaults in your `/select` handler.

```
<str name="mlt.fl">one, two, three </str>

    <str name="mlt.mintf">2</str>

    <str name="rows">10</str>

    <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>

    <str name="mlt.boost">true</str>
```

Copy above into /select handler definition, paste in defaults section.

```
<lst name="defaults"> paste here </lst>
```

OR

update request handler name with `/` like `name="/mlt_tracks"`

```
<requestHandler name="/mlt_tracks" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
```

And use `/mlt_tracks` instead of /select to query

```
http://IP_ADDRESS:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/mlt_tracks?indent=on&q=one:ABC&mlt=true&mlt.fl=one,two,three&&rows=100&start=1&wt=json
```

Comment: Restart solr after modification as above in solrconfig.xml file.

Comment: Could you also add an explanation of why this changes how `start` is interpreted? (you're now [actually working with the result from "More like this"](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis), instead of the original result set)

Comment: `start` tells from where it should begin to return documents in result. it starts from 0. if start=1, it skips first document.